# Issue upgrading to iOS 10.0 or later on an iPad 2

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iPad 2 running iOS 9.3.5.  I would like to install the kindle app. But that requires me to upgrade to iOS 10.0 or later.  If I go to General->Software Update, it says "Your software is up to date".  Unfortunately, I am not able to find any other way to upgrade the iOS version. Can you help me ?

Comment: You can install older version of some apps

Answer (score 2):

iPad 2 does not support iOS 10. The last version of iOS you can install on an iPad 2 is iOS 9.3.5.